# Parar generator

Tags: python-3.x, generators

Qual seria a melhor forma de parar um generator? Exemplo:

```
>>> def get_fruits():
        fruits = ['Mamão', 'Abacate', 'Melão', 'Banana', 'Maçã', 'Uva']

        for fruit in fruits:
            yield fruit


>>> my_bag = []
>>> salesman_fruits = get_fruits()
>>> 
>>> for fruit in salesman_fruits:
        my_bag.append(fruit)
        if fruit is 'Banana':
            salesman_fruits.close() # Chega não quero mais frutas
```

Essa foi a forma que eu encontrei para parar o gnerator de fora dele, ou seja, para que o generator rode enquanto até que o "usuário" diga que não quer mais.
Minha dúvida é que não sei se o método close() do generetor é para esse fim ou eu estou fazendo uso equivocado dele.

Comment: O que você quer que aconteça com o gerador após terminar de usá-lo? Você pode simplesmente parar o seu loop com `break` quando não quiser mais frutas. Não precisa parar o gerador. Talvez você precise dar um exemplo melhor.

Comment: @Pablo, eu resolvi parar dessa forma pois o loop interno do generator continuaria mesmo eu dando um break no for que percorre o generator.
Vamos supor que no corpo do interator tivesse um loop infinito:
[http://paste.ubuntu.com/15023506/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15023506/)

Isso causaria um loop infinito, visto que o `break` é para o loop `for`

Comment: Tem razão! Mas, pelo que li aqui, parece que o .close() é a forma correta de gerar a StopIteration que o Dener citou. Veja: https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma boa forma de lidar com isso é utilizar o [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration), ele é lançado pelo `next()` do [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), método para sinalizar que não ha mais valores, neste caso o uso é dentro do método `get_fruits()`. Ele é derivado de um [Exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) em vez de um [StandardError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StandardError) desde que isso não seja considerado um erro em sua aplicação normal.

Veja esta adaptação do `StopIteration`:

```
def get_fruits():
    fruits = ['Mamão', 'Abacate', 'Melão', 'Banana', 'Maçã', 'Uva'] 

    for fruit in fruits:
        yield fruit
        if fruit is 'Banana':
            raise StopIteration    

my_bag = []
salesman_fruits = get_fruits()

for fruit in salesman_fruits:
    my_bag.append(fruit)
    #if fruit is 'Banana':
        #salesman_fruits.close() # Chega não quero mais frutas

for fruit in my_bag: 
    print(fruit)
```

Saída:

> Mamão
>   Abacate
>   Melão
>   Banana

Neste caso eu usei a sua condição `if fruit is 'Banana'` para parar a interação do generator.

Fonte:
[yield break in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395063/yield-break-in-python)